# modulenotfound Python 3.6.5 , Spyder 3.2.8

Tags: python

I have installed Anaconda, Python 3.6.5 and Spyder 3.2.8.
 I have installed the lime package using the below command in Anaconda prompt.

```
conda install -c conda-forge lime
```

While it shows no error in Anaconda prompt but when I use import lime in Spyder, it's throwing following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lime'

Appreciate help on solving this in Sypder